# How do add a month to a date in Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, date, thymeleaf

I have `${{status.startDate}}`, and I would like to show `${{status.startDate + 1 month}}`

How could I do that with Thymeleaf, without doing it in my Controller or Translator or using any other module ?

Comment: What type is `startDate`? `java.util.Date`?

Comment: java.time.LocalDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can just use the defined methods of LocalDate...

```
${{status.startDate.plusMonths(1)}}
```